# Mapbox WMTS layer in QGIS poor print quality

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapbox

I've added a Mapbox WMTS [layer](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-arcgis-qgis/#build-a-wmts-endpoint-1) to my QGIS project.

However when I use the print composer and export my map the result is blurry / not sharp. The image in the print composer itself is sharp, it is only after export that the problems occur. Any idea how to solve this? I've also tried exporting as PDF but the result is the same low quality.

I also tried increasing DPI and total number of pixels but the results are disappointing.

[image]

Comment: Is your QGIS project in the same CRS as the Mapbox layer? Projecting a tiled layer into a different CRS can result in blurry labels.

Comment: Yes Both Web Mercator

Answer (score 4):

The Mapbox WMTS endpoint only supports @1x resolution, but in QGIS 3 you can add an XYZ Tiles source and use the @2x resolution Mapbox tiles. Something like

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/USERNAME/STYLE_ID/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you're happy for your icon/text to become smaller you can get even more resolution by requesting 512 @2x tiles instead of 256 tiles

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/USERNAME/STYLE_ID/tiles/512/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Where did you find the information about the XYZ mapbox tiles?

Comment: The problem is that the map is only unsharp after export. Before export resolution is fine.

Comment: https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles under "Retrieve raster tiles from styles"

Comment: Sure, this might not be the issue, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: I've also come across this problem - it seems to relate to the tiles being pulled in when you export at a zoom level that is different that what is seen in the composer window. I can get around by it setting the min and max zoom levels (in my case to 2 and 6, respectively); by also increasing the resolution per the answer above it seems to somewhat get around the problem for me.

Comment: A bit of clarification on some things that tripped me up (thanks Mapbox support for the help): 
1. I was looking in "Layer --> Add Layer" and couldn't find XYZ Tiles, trying (and failing) with "Add Raster Layer". Instead, use the Browser panel and add from the XYZ Tiles section there.
2. I found that the 256 tile size worked best for me, but I think this can depend on scale and print size
3. The appropriate link in the Mapbox docs is not the raster tiles section, but the static tiles section: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-tiles

I'm using QGIS 3.10. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same context, but I've beat my head against a wall with WM(T)S print quality and symbol/font size issues arising from different screen and print layout DPI, though it wasn't Mapbox as a source.

As a workaround, I've **exported** (`Export / Save as...`) the **layer as a raster** over my whole ROI, manually setting the resolution to correspond to the correct one for the target zoom layer (or fiddling with it to get the symbol/font sizes I wanted). Then I use my locally saved raster in lieu of the original layer in my print layout.

There are downsides, of course, but especially if your print area stays constant, it may be more efficient in terms of your time.

Starting with QGIS 3.14, you could also use **vector tiles** if you're using a standard source map. See https://www.maptiler.com/news/2020/06/vector-tiles-in-qgis-3-14/, though cost may be prohibitive.